# What is the correct way of determining the launch time of an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Using the Azure REST API (or any tool that communicates over the REST API, such as the [azure-cli](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli)), what would be the correct way to determine the age of a VM or find out the time when the VM was booted?

Neither `az vm list` nor `az vm get-instance-view` appears to give me an obvious answer.

My first assumption was that the `statuses` seen when running `az vm get-instance-view` would indicate the boot time via the `time` of the `provisioningState` (as in the example below), *however*, this timestamp gets updated if I, for instance, set a new tag on the VM.

```
"statuses": [
          {
            "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
            "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
            "level": "Info",
            "message": null,
            "time": "2016-12-08T09:45:14.956230+00:00"
          },
          {
            "code": "PowerState/running",
            "displayStatus": "VM running",
            "level": "Info",
            "message": null,
            "time": null
          }
        ]
```

Although a bit far-fetched, my main candidate so far is the `time` found on the OS disk's provisioning status:

```
  "instanceView": {
    "bootDiagnostics": null,
    "disks": [
      {
        "name": "testvm-1480595334683-os-disk",
        "statuses": [
          {
            "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
            "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
            "level": "Info",
            "message": null,
            "time": "2016-12-01T12:30:35.583526+00:00"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I've searched for any official documentation on this topic but come up empty-handed. I'm assuming that there *is* a way, since I can come up with several reasons why it would be useful to know the age of a VM.

Comment: As far as i know, there is no way to use PowerShell or CLI to find the time when the VM was rebooted direct. Maybe we can use Custom Script For Linux or windows to list the uptime, Linux can use command uptime to list the time, windows can use  systeminfo | find "System Boot Time" to list.

Comment: I can't even seem to find it in the portal. Do you know if the (first) launch time can be viewed there? I mean, since Microsoft charges me per-minute, they *know* how long it has been running. It just baffles me that there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to find out about this _very_ basic meta data.

Comment: We can use Azure portal to find the time when the VM has created. login the new portal, and select the VM, in the overview, we can find the Activity log, in this way, we can find the write virtualmachines time, this time is the VM created time.

Comment: Yes, I guess that is one way to actually do it. Do you know if the activity log can be accessed from the REST API?

Comment: The Activity Log does not include read (GET) operations. We can retrieve events from your Activity log using the Azure portal, CLI, PowerShell cmdlets, and Azure Monitor REST API. More information about Activity log, please refer to the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out the REST API. Unfortunately, the monitoring REST API does not appear to be supported yet in the Java SDK, which I'm currently using but it's still in beta so it may be included later.

Answer (score 0):

Here another way to find the launch time of Azure VM. we can use Azure portal view my bill to check the computer hours:
[image]
[image]
Hope this helps you.